# Perform Histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use histogram graph to plot my Provider State in the X-axis and the MaxCost variable in the Y-axis. I also want my third variable(DRG.Code) to be present on top of each histogram plot. How can I make this plot using ggplot?

```
> dput(head(group4))  
structure(list(DRG.Code = structure(c(31L, 92L, 64L, 25L, 25L, 
25L), .Label = c("039 ", "057 ", "064 ", "065 ", "066 ", "069 ", 
"092 ", "100 ", "101 ", "175 ", "176 ", "177 ", "178 ", "180 ", 
"189 ", "190 ", "191 ", "192 ", "193 ", "194 ", "195 ", "202 ", 
"207 ", "208 ", "234 ", "243 ", "246 ", "247 ", "252 ", "253 ", 
"269 ", "280 ", "281 ", "282 ", "286 ", "287 ", "291 ", "292 ", 
"293 ", "300 ", "305 ", "308 ", "309 ", "310 ", "312 ", "313 ", 
"314 ", "329 ", "330 ", "331 ", "371 ", "372 ", "377 ", "378 ", 
"379 ", "389 ", "390 ", "391 ", "392 ", "393 ", "394 ", "418 ", 
"439 ", "460 ", "469 ", "470 ", "473 ", "480 ", "481 ", "482 ", 
"483 ", "536 ", "552 ", "563 ", "602 ", "603 ", "637 ", "638 ", 
"640 ", "641 ", "682 ", "683 ", "684 ", "689 ", "690 ", "698 ", 
"699 ", "811 ", "812 ", "853 ", "854 ", "870 ", "871 ", "872 ", 
"897 ", "917 ", "918 ", "948 ", "981 ", "982 "), class = "factor"), 
Provider.State.x = structure(c(3L, 17L, 25L, 26L, 2L, 20L
), .Label = c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", 
"DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", 
"LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", 
"ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", 
"PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", "VT", "WA", 
"WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor"), MaxCost = c(2714.51, 
3104.02833333333, 3139.14214285714, 3223.30777777778, 3731.276, 
3787.29666666667)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use `geom_col()`

A histogram with only one value is a bar chart.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=Provider.State.x, y = MaxCost, fill = DRG.Code)) + 
geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked!!